# SSRS: Dynamically Creating New Matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have the following format in my dataset (see Dataset Layout screenshot).

[image: Dataset Layout]

I need this report to show like the following (see Report Layout screenshot) with a bit of a difference, but first let me explain.

[image: Report Layout]

This report is a "monthly" report that shows the data for each day of a given month.  What I have shown in the Report Layout screen shot is how the report displays if the user only selects one available value for column "Level!2!Sample".  So in other words, instead of seeing multiple values in that column as shown in the screen print, it would only contain one distinct value.  This report works when only one item is available, but I need to allow for multiple options.

What I need to do is be able to display data like this for multiple values of "Level!2!Sample", and each time a new "Level!2!Sample" is encountered, it would create a new matrix as shown in the screen print.  So if there are four distinct items for this column, I would have four different tables shown on the report, each displaying the data for the given distinct value of the "Level!2!Sample" column.

I assume I would need to use an "Order By" clause to get my data looking correctly:
Order By
     Level!2!Sample, 
     name!3!Title, 
     month!4!ReportMonth

But I am not sure how to get SSRS to create a new matrix when the new level!2!sample record is encountered.

I hope my explanation makes sense as to what I am trying to do.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a new matrix like that but there are other options.

Simple option: Create one big matrix grouped by Level!2!Sample and have page break between groups. This would obviously mean you would end up with 4 pages in your sample scenario which may not be ideal.

Slightly less simple option:

1. Create a new report
2. Include your parameter as you did for the current report.
3. Add a dataset (let's call it `dsLoop`) that returns a single column and 1 record per selected parameter entry. This might look something like `SELECT DISTINCT Level!2!Sample FROM myTable WHERE Level!2!Sample IN(@myParameter)`.
4. Add a table with a single column and a single row and set it's width to the width of your report/page.
5. Set the dataset for the table to be `dsLoop`
6. In the table's cell insert a subreport and set the subreport properties to point to your original report
7. Set the subreport parameter to Level!2!Sample from your dataset.

**Notes:**

*a. You can get rid of the available values and related datasets from your original report as these are no longer needed (optional)*

*b. You can add rows before or after the cell with the subreport if you want to add gaps between each tablix.*

Basically your new report acts as a loop and creates one row per selected item in the parameter list, each row contains an entire subreport with the parameter for the current row passed to it.

The net result is that you will get a 'new'  table for each selected entry.

Hope that makes sense.